# Help identifying this finite group I have characterised (subgroup of $(C_3 \wr C_3)^3$

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

I'm working on a group for my master's thesis and I've found a fairly precise characterisation of it, but I can't see how to describe it as a combination of standard groups.
I have characterised it as
$$(\alpha^{i_1}\gamma^{i_2}L_0, \alpha^{i_2}\gamma^{i_3}L_0, \alpha^{i_3}\gamma^{i_1}L_0),$$

where both $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are of degree 3 and $L_0$ is a group isomorphic to $C_3 \times C_3$.

(In other words an element of this group is characterised by the three numbers $i_1$, $i_2$ and $i_3$, and by three elements in $L_0$, giving the group $3^3*9^3 = 3^9$ elements.

Has anyone got an idea how to better describe this?

EDIT: As mentioned below I've given much too little information about this group. The group is a subgroup of $C_3 \wr C_3$, where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are the generators of the respective cyclic groups.

$L_0$ is a normal subgroup of $C_3 \wr C_3$, and more precisely of the subgroup of elements whose $\alpha$-coordinate is nil ($C_3 \wr C_3 \cong C_3 \ltimes C_3^3$, and what I'm saying is that $L_0$ is inside the $\{1\} \ltimes C_3^3$ part).

The group I'm investigating in general is the group generated by $(\alpha, 1, \gamma)$, $(\gamma, \alpha, 1)$ and $(1, \gamma, \alpha)$, and I have managed to reduce it to the above characterisation.

Comment: So how do you multiply those elements? Just component-wise?

Comment: Even if the answer is "componentwise" we need a lot more information, there are quite a few groups of order $81$ with a subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_3^2$ with complement $\mathbb{Z}_3^2$..

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_81

Comment: As mentioned, there was a lot of information missing, and I hope I have managed to fix the problems.

Comment: I am afraid that I still cannot make much sense of this. But you might be out of luck anyway. There is a huge number of groups of order $3^9$ (I don't think the exact number is known), and the majority of those cannot be described as a combination of standard groups (whatever that means). In general, the only way that you can uniquely define a typical group of that order is by a certain type of presentation known as a power-commutator presentation.